# How to handle 2d avatar creation

Tags: sprites, spritesheet, avatar

I am new to game design and i am creating a MMORPG that allows players to create 2d avatars that can be customized. If i had lets say a male character model (no equipment no armor). How would i handle body variation for this male model? If this has been answered please provide link. I know layering customizing for equipment and armor has but not morphing the character sprite itself.

Comment: Don't "morph" the sprite, treat the components of the sprite you can customize (head, arms, torso, legs, feet, whatever) exactly the same as you would "equipment" and composite them accordingly.

Comment: thanks @JoshPetrie i was trying to actually direct message you even looked for you on facebook couldnt find you